# SQL tree recursive mean of children values

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am currently designing a catalogue system. It has 2 types of items: categories and items themselves. There also may be nested categories and some items may have a parent which is always some category.
So the table looks like:

```sql
create table items
(
    id        uuid,
    parent    uuid,
    name      text,
    type      text,
    cost      int,

    primary key (id),
    constraint constraint_on_parent
        foreign key (parent)
            references items (id)
);
```

Another thing to mention is that all the category items have a cost equals to null (well, after all, you cannot buy a category itself, right?).
Now I need to come up with an sql query which would, given an item id, return itself and all its children in case it is a category. Also if it is a category, then I would like to get the average price of its children (also applies to the sub-categories).
So far I have managed to create a recursive query which retrieves itself and the children:

```sql
with recursive query as (
    select id, name, type, cost
    from items
    where id=$item_id
    union all
    select it.id, it.name, it.type, it.cost
    from items it inner join query q on q.id = it.parent
)
select id, name
from children
```

However, now I am wondering, how can I change it to calculate the mean price of thecategory and its subcateogries recursively?
Also, I am using PostgreSQL 14.

Edit 1: Sample data and desired output
**Sample data**

| id | parent | name | type | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | null | root | category | null |
| uuid2 | uuid1 | item1 | item | 100 |
| uuid3 | uuid1 | subcategory1 | category | null |
| uuid4 | uuid3 | item2 | item | 200 |
| uuid5 | uuid3 | item3 | item | 300 |

**Desired ouput**
When run the described query against *uuid3* I expect to get something like

| id | parent | name | type | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid3 | uuid1 | subcategory1 | category | 250 |
| uuid4 | uuid3 | item2 | item | 200 |
| uuid5 | uuid3 | item3 | item | 300 |

This output looks like the 3 last rows of the sample data, except for the first row, the category, having a price equal to the mean price of its children
When run the described query against *uuid1* I expect to get

| id | parent | name | type | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | null | root | category | 200 |
| uuid2 | uuid1 | item1 | item | 100 |
| uuid3 | uuid1 | subcategory1 | category | 250 |
| uuid4 | uuid3 | item2 | item | 200 |
| uuid5 | uuid3 | item3 | item | 300 |

Here `subcategory1` price is the mean of `item2` and `item3` costs, `root` price is the mean of `item1`, `item2` and `items3` costs.
Also, if the category has no items in it, its price should remain null

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ARRAY to store path to the item

```
with recursive query as (
    select id, name, type, cost, array[id] path
    from items
    where id='uuid1'
    union all
    select it.id, it.name, it.type, it.cost, array_append(path, it.id)
    from items it inner join query q on q.id = it.parent
)
select  t1.id, t1.name, t1.type, avg(t2.cost) cost
from query t1
left join query t2 on t2.path @> Array[t1.id]
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.type;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2bb52f1c045e8fa0df62b222c6f93848)

Returns

```
id  name    type    cost
uuid1   root    category    200.0000000000000000
uuid2   item1   item    100.0000000000000000
uuid3   subcategory1    category    250.0000000000000000
uuid4   item2   item    200.0000000000000000
uuid5   item3   item    300.0000000000000000
```